# Buttons don't stack vertically at breakpoint in Bootstrap 4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to have a series of divs displayed horizontally, except when the screen size goes below sm and then would stack vertically.  This seems like it should be simple...I had it working with Bootstrap 3 but for some reason when I upgraded to Bootstrap 4 it stopped working.  I tried changing the breakpoint to col-md-10, col-md-3 etc to allow for the new Bootstrap 4 screen sizes but it still doesn't work even on an xs screen.  What am I missing?

```
        <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-10 offset-xs-4 offset-md-2 btn-group">
                <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 button button-header button-tools-collections"><a href="<?php echo site_url('products/tools/'); ?>"><h3>Tools</h3>  <span class="badge"><span class="fa fa-wrench fa-2x"></span></span></a></div>
                <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 button button-header button-tools-collections"><a href="<?php echo site_url('products/collections/'); ?>"><h3>Collections</h3>  <span class="badge"><span class="fa fa-folder-open fa-2x"></span></span></a></div>
                <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 button button-header button-tools-collections"><a href="<?php echo site_url('cooperative/regional_projects/'); ?>"><h3>Regional Projects</h3>  <span class="badge"><span class="fa fa-globe fa-2x"></span></span></a></div>
            </div>
        </div>  
        </div>
```

Using bootstrap 3 the xs screen looks as it should:

[image: Boostrap 3]

Bootstrap 4 the buttons remain inline
[image: Bootstrap 4]

```
.button-header {
    border: 3px solid #b8d87a;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: .8em;
    margin: 2em 1em 2em 0;
}
.button-header a {
    color: #fff;
    padding: .5em 1em;
    display: block;
}

.button-header a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}

.button-tools-collections a {
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [Bootstrap's migration documentation for 4.x](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/migration/)

> Revamped grid tiers to add a fifth option (addressing smaller devices
> at 576px and below) and removed the `-xs` infix from those classes.
> Example: `.col-6.col-sm-4.col-md-3`.

The smallest breakpoint is now `col-*` instead of `col-xs-*` so in your above code the smallest breakpoint that would be honored in 4.x is `col-sm-3`

Modifying your code to honor Bootstrap 4.x classes it might look something like:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-+4zCK9k+qNFUR5X+cKL9EIR+ZOhtIloNl9GIKS57V1MyNsYpYcUrUeQc9vNfzsWfV28IaLL3i96P9sdNyeRssA==" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-10">
      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
          <a href="#null">
            <h3>Tools</h3>
            <span class="badge">
              <span class="fa fa-wrench fa-2x"></span>
            </span>
          </a>
        </div>

        <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
          <a href="#null">
            <h3>Collections</h3>
            <span class="badge">
              <span class="fa fa-folder-open fa-2x"></span>
            </span>
          </a>
        </div>

        <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
          <a href="#null">
            <h3>Regional Projects</h3>
            <span class="badge">
              <span class="fa fa-globe fa-2x"></span>
            </span>
          </a>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Please note that applying the `.btn-group` class to a Grid wrapper element overrides certain Grid component behavior.  In the above example I have removed that class.

Answer (score 0):

The main difference is actualy coming from the fact that class `btn-group` in bootstrap 4 is `display: inline-flex;` while it was `display: inline-block;`in BS3. So set `d-inline-block` to get same way as BS3.